# How can I delete certain row/rows from sqlite table using Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Here is the code I wrote. But when compiling, it says that LIMIT and OFFSET is not defined.

```
def sql_delete(user_id, task_number):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM tasks WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?)', (user_id, task_number, ))
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

Just now I understood what you did want to manage. Just give a try this:

```
def sql_delete(user_id, task_number):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM tasks WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM tasks WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?)', (user_id, int(task_number)))
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you!
Do you know how to delete row on position task_number?
I thought that my previous code was for that, but you added offset_number...

Comment: @AdletZeineken I added offset number because you had it in the first place so I showed you the correct way. I don't know what exactly you want  your query to do. Do you want to delete a specific task from a specific user?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete row for user_id that is on position task_number. I.e. I want to delete nth row for user_id. Would be great if you will show how to do that.